# how to get context which method is applied to

Tags: javascript

**deprecated**: bad example

Is it feasible to get execution context (object reference) which method is applied to not passing additional reference of 'someObject' as 'someMethod' argument in last line of code?

```
var someObject = {
    prop1 : 'value1'
};

var someMethod = function() {
    // TODO: how to get prop1 value from here?
};

someMethod.call(someObject);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.prop1` will do the magic for you.

Comment: @nEEbz: is it so hard to try before posting?
Test for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Uqfhj/

Comment: sorry I totally missed out on the `.call()` . Obviously your's is the most elegant way in the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

simply `someObject.prop1` will get you the value

Comment: let assume someObject is not global variable then it will not work. It would be great to get it somehow like caller function by argumets.callee.caller

Comment: Didn't really get your point clearly but I do have an instinct that you could achieve something like that using Javascript `prototypes` . Though a little bit more clarification would help

Comment: @Mykhaylo - I don't follow you.  Are you trying to access a local variable of calling function from within the called function?